# Storybook doesn't see stories with new syntax - NX with React Native

Tags: react-native, storybook, nrwl-nx

I have a project with NX, react native and storybook. When I run the app and toggle storybook on device, it only picks up the stories with the deprecated syntax (using storiesof) and not the newer syntax. Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.7.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@nrwl/detox": "15.9.2",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.9.2",
    "@nrwl/jest": "15.9.2",
    "@nrwl/js": "15.9.2",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.9.2",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/react-native": "15.9.2",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "15.9.2",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.9.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "10.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "10.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "10.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^6.0.1-beta.11",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-backgrounds": "^6.0.1-beta.11",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-controls": "^6.0.1-beta.11",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-notes": "^6.0.1-beta.11",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/core-server": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^6.0.1-beta.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "5.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "11.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "18.14.4",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-native": "0.71.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.1",
    "detox": "~20.5.0",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-circus": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-react-native": "18.0.0",
    "metro": "0.74.1",
    "metro-babel-register": "0.74.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.74.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-transformer": "0.74.1",
    "metro-resolver": "0.74.1",
    "nx": "15.9.2",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-config": "1.5.0",
    "react-native-storybook-loader": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-svg": "13.8.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
}
```

The stories are definitely imported in .storybook/story-loader:

```
function loadStories() {
  require('../libs/shared-ui-atoms/src/lib/generic-button/GenericButton.stories');
  require('../libs/shared-ui-layout/src/lib/generic-dialog/GenericDialog.stories');
}

const stories = [
  '../libs/shared-ui-atoms/src/lib/generic-button/GenericButton.stories',
  '../libs/shared-ui-layout/src/lib/generic-dialog/GenericDialog.stories',
];

module.exports = {
  loadStories,
  stories,
};
```

GenericDialog shows up fine and here is what it looks like:

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { GenericDialog, GenericDialogProps } from './GenericDialog';

const props: GenericDialogProps = {
  title: '',
};

storiesOf('GenericDialog', module).add('Primary', () => (
  <GenericDialog {...props} />
));
```

GenericButton doesn't show ever since i changed the syntax:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react-native';
import { GenericButton } from './GenericButton';

const meta: Meta<typeof GenericButton> = {
  title: 'Button',
  component: GenericButton,
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof GenericButton>;

export const Primary: Story = {
  args: {},
};
```

I searched NX guides, Storybook guides, posted on their slack, combed through their issues but can't find what is going wrong here. I need the new syntax stories to show up.

Comment: You should update the version to 6.5.4 and also there is no longer any need for  storyloader. I recommend following the new tutorial to get an idea of how it should work. Unfortunately the nx template hasn't been updated yet.